# Client/Server works on local windows machine but fails on Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: python, linux, networking, encryption, scapy

I am trying to build a network client that hides secret messages in the data section of an ICMP Echo packet, as well as a network server that captures the Echo packets and decrypts/prints the secret messages.

My server/listener seems to receive and correctly print the message sent from the client on my windows local machine but it does function on my linux virtual machine and I am not sure why. additionally, I can't see any of my traffic when i filter for icmp on wireshark

below is my code of the client:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP
import random
# from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
# from encryption import KEY  # shared key for decryption

from encryption import load_key
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = 'ZmDfcTF7_60GrrY167zsiPd67pEvs0aGOv2oasOM1Pg='
# load_key()
f = Fernet(key)
class CovertHeader(scapy.Packet):
    '''
    This class defines a header for use with your encrypted message.
    You may define additional header fields if you want or need to. The seqNum
    field is used to help reorder messages, and len is the length of data
    following this header.
    '''
    name = "Covert Comms Channel Header"
    fields_desc = [scapy.ByteField("ID", 0),  # ID used to pair packets
                   scapy.ByteField("len", 0),  # length of data
                   scapy.BitField("final", 0, 1),  # bit set to 1 for final packet
                   scapy.BitField("seqNum", 0, 15)]  # sequence number of current message

def sendPacket(msg, seqNum, id, msgLength, payload):
    '''
    Send packet is called to send message.
    msg: 100 byte chunks of the message
    seqNum: the current sequence number
    id: identifier used to group packets at receiver
    msgLength: used to determine when the last packet is sent
    payload: actual size of payload - padding
    '''
    pkt = IP(src=IP_SRC, dst=IP_DST, proto=PROTO_ICMP)
    pkt = pkt / ICMP(type=ECHO_ICMP_TYPE, code=ECHO_ICMP_CODE)
    pkt = pkt / CovertHeader()
    pkt = pkt / msg
    print('The current sequence number is: ', seqNum)
    pkt[CovertHeader].seqNum = seqNum
    pkt[CovertHeader].ID = id
    pkt[CovertHeader].len = 128 + payload
    if msgLength == 0:
        pkt[CovertHeader].final = 1
    sendSock.send(pkt)
    print(f'Sent packet with payload length: {payload} \nID: {id}')

# IPs, protocol, type, and code
IP_SRC = '127.0.0.1'
IP_DST = input("Enter Destination Address [Recommend 127.0.0.1]: ")
PROTO_ICMP = 1
ECHO_ICMP_TYPE = 8
ECHO_ICMP_CODE = 0

scapy.conf.L3socket = scapy.conf.L3socket()
sendSock = scapy.conf.L3socket

msg = input('Enter your message:  ')
# f = Fernet(KEY)

encMsg = msg.encode()
print('message length: ', len(encMsg), 'bytes')

msgList = []
done = False
chunkStart = 0
chunkEnd = 80

while not done:
    # split into 80 byte chunks
    #msgChunk = encMsg[chunkStart:chunkEnd]
    #chunkStart = chunkStart + 80
    #chunkEnd = chunkEnd + 80
    #msgList.append(msgChunk)
    #if chunkStart > len(encMsg):
     #   done = True
      #  break
    #elif chunkEnd > len(encMsg):
     #   msgList.append(encMsg[chunkStart:])
      #  done = True

    # apply padding if not 80 bytes
    while not done:
        msgChunk = encMsg[chunkStart:chunkEnd]
        chunkStart = chunkStart + 80
        chunkEnd = chunkEnd + 80
        # Check if the chunk is less than 80 bytes and pad it if necessary
        if len(msgChunk) < 80:
            msgChunk = msgChunk.ljust(80, b'\x00')
        msgList.append(msgChunk)
        if chunkStart > len(encMsg):
            done = True

msgLength = len(encMsg)
seqNum = random.randint(0, 32766)
id = random.randint(1, 255)

for i in range(len(msgList)):
    curMsg = msgList[i]
    szPayload = len(msgList[i])
    msgLength = 1 if i < len(msgList) - 1 else 0

    sendPacket(curMsg, seqNum, id, msgLength, szPayload)

# Function to receive and process packets
def receivePackets():
    def process_packet(pkt):
        if pkt.haslayer(CovertHeader):
            print("Received response: ", pkt[CovertHeader].load.decode())
    scapy.sniff(filter="icmp", prn=process_packet, count=5, timeout=10)

# Function to handle image data
def handle_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        image_data = image_file.read()
    chunks = [image_data[i:i+80] for i in range(0, len(image_data), 80)]
    return chunks

# Main function to send messages or images
def main():
    choice = input("Send message (M) or image (I)? ")
    if choice.lower() == 'm':
        msg = input('Enter your message:  ')
        encMsg = f.encrypt(msg.encode())
        chunkStart, chunkEnd = 0, 80
        seqNum = random.randint(0, 32766)
        id = random.randint(1, 255)
        while chunkStart < len(encMsg):
            curMsg = encMsg[chunkStart:chunkEnd]
            szPayload = len(curMsg)
            msgLength = 0 if chunkEnd >= len(encMsg) else 1
            sendPacket(curMsg, seqNum, id, msgLength, szPayload)
            chunkStart += 80
            chunkEnd += 80
            seqNum += 1  # Increment sequence number for each packet

    elif choice.lower() == 'i':
        image_path = input('Enter  [ABSOLUTE]: ')
        image_chunks = handle_image(image_path)
        seqNum = random.randint(0, 32766)
        id = random.randint(1, 255)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(image_chunks):
            szPayload = len(chunk)
            msgLength = 0 if i == len(image_chunks) - 1 else 1
            sendPacket(chunk, seqNum, id, msgLength, szPayload)
            seqNum += 1  # Increment sequence number for each packet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    receivePackets()
```

below is my code of the listener/server:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP
# from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
# from encryption import KEY

from encryption import load_key
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

#key = 'tkXHvFr4PCJGFfbPPxStZ6MYUj30D1x5aMOrIkvt2tk'
#key = Fernet.generate_key()
key = 'ZmDfcTF7_60GrrY167zsiPd67pEvs0aGOv2oasOM1Pg='
f = Fernet(key)

class CovertHeader(scapy.Packet):
    '''
    This class defines a header for use with your encrypted message.
    '''
    name = "Covert Comms Channel Header"
    fields_desc = [scapy.ByteField("ID", 0),
                   scapy.ByteField("len", 0),
                   scapy.BitField("final", 0, 1),
                   scapy.BitField("seqNum", 0, 15)]

finalMsg = ""
# f = Fernet(KEY)

def process_icmp_only(pkt):
    '''
    Filter the packets one at a time as received.
    '''
    if pkt.haslayer(ICMP):  # Updated to use the directly imported ICMP
        if pkt[ICMP].type == 8:
            pkt[ICMP].decode_payload_as(CovertHeader)
            print('Received covert ICMP packet, processing')
            global finalMsg
            finalMsg = finalMsg + pkt[CovertHeader].load.decode()
            if pkt[CovertHeader].final == 1:
                print(finalMsg)
                finalMsg = ""

scapy.conf.L3socket = scapy.conf.L3socket()
rcvSock = scapy.conf.L3socket
print("The Server is currently running...")
while True:
    try:
        rcvSock.sniff(count=1, prn=process_icmp_only)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        exit()
    except:
        continue

# Function to send a response back to the client
def sendResponse(response, dest_ip):
    response_pkt = IP(dst=dest_ip) / ICMP() / CovertHeader() / response.encode()  # Using the directly imported ICMP
    scapy.send(response_pkt)

# Main function to process and respond to messages or images
def main():
    def process_packet(pkt):
        if pkt.haslayer(ICMP) and pkt.haslayer(CovertHeader):  # Using the directly imported ICMP
            print("Received message: ", pkt[CovertHeader].load.decode())
            sendResponse("Ack: Message received", pkt[IP].src)

    print("Listener Running...")
    scapy.sniff(filter="icmp", prn=process_packet, count=10, timeout=20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**ICMP Filtering in Wireshark:** The issue of not being able to see ICMP traffic in Wireshark might be due to the fact that ICMP packets are often blocked by firewalls. Make sure that the firewall on your Linux virtual machine is not blocking ICMP traffic.

**ICMP ID Field:** In your sendPacket function, you set the ID field of the CovertHeader to a random value. However, in your process_icmp_only function on the server side, you are not checking whether the received packet has the expected ID. You might want to add a check for the ID field to make sure you are processing the correct packets.

Add this check in the **process_icmp_only** function:

```
def process_icmp_only(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(ICMP) and pkt.haslayer(CovertHeader):
        if pkt[ICMP].type == 8 and pkt[CovertHeader].ID == expected_id:
            # ... rest of the code
```

**Timeout in Sniffing:** In your server's main function, you are using scapy.sniff with a timeout of 20 seconds and a count of 10. This means it will only capture up to 10 packets or wait for 20 seconds before exiting. Adjust the timeout and count values based on your requirements.

Change this line:

```
scapy.sniff(filter="icmp", prn=process_packet, count=10, timeout=20)
```

To something like this:

```
scapy.sniff(filter="icmp", prn=process_packet, count=0, timeout=None)
This will make it wait indefinitely until interrupted.
```

Packet Sending: The client sends packets with a payload, but the server sends an empty payload back as an acknowledgment. If you intend to acknowledge the received message, you should include the acknowledgment message in the response.

Modify the sendResponse function to include a meaningful acknowledgment message:

```
def sendResponse(response, dest_ip):
    response_pkt = IP(dst=dest_ip) / ICMP() / CovertHeader() / response.encode()
    scapy.send(response_pkt)
```

Then, in your process_packet function, you can print the acknowledgment message:

```
def process_packet(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(ICMP) and pkt.haslayer(CovertHeader):
        if pkt[ICMP].type == 8 and pkt[CovertHeader].ID == expected_id:
            print("Received message: ", pkt[CovertHeader].load.decode())
            sendResponse("Ack: Message received", pkt[IP].src)
```

Make sure to address these points, and it should help in troubleshooting the issues you are facing. Additionally, check for any error messages or exceptions that might be raised during execution on your Linux virtual machine.

Comment: thanks for response, instead of sendResponse did you mean sendPacket? also where should i define the expected_id?